# My data is not showing when adding delimited text layer with lat/long

Tags: qgis, csv

This is my screenshot of Data Source Manager of Delimited Text input. Sample data look fine.
[image]

When I press 'Add' no data shows. World Map layer is EPSG-4326-WGS 84. I tried everything but the data still not showing.

Comment: You location lat, long does not look EPSG:4326 but rather in a projected CRS. You need to change CRS (Geometric SRC)

Comment: If your data is in Brazil then you are probably missing the decimal separator : -22.934682, -43.099864 which would be valid EPSG:4326 coordinales. I think your decimal seperator either . or , got most likely lost somewhere

Answer (score 2):

In the World Geodetic System 1984 (WGS84) coordinate system, latitude  values range from -90 to 90; longitude  values range from -180 to 180.

The values of your coordinates are out of the specified limits.

Answer (score 1):

Divide your latitude and longitude values by 1 million, e.g. (-22934682, -43099864) becomes (-22.934682, -43.099864) locating in Rio de Janeiro.